# Share sessions between versions/backends in google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I have a fairly big application hosted on appengine. It has various components and each component is done by a different group in the company.

I am looking to break down the application into various submodules each hosted separately as a  version. eg: module1.mainapp.com.

Since Google uses a db for sharing sessions and the db is shared among the versions and backends, is there a way to share sessions? Currently, it looks like each session is different.

I understand that we can put `<SessionCookie domain="example.com"/>` in web.xml in normal applications but I am not sure if AppEngine honors this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking to share the session between the versions and backends.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, because cookies are set by the user system, and the cookies are per domain.

In any case, I wouldn't recommend this approach - modifying your URL scheme to suit your app's internal organization is a nasty hack; the URL scheme you present to your users needn't have any direct relationship with how you handle requests.

Comment: Cookies can be set for all subdomains too. I will add that to the original problem statement.

Comment: @cloudpre Yes, but the App Engine users API doesn't do that. I'm not sure whether you can do that using the Java session support - you didn't mention you were using Java. I still think this is a terrible idea, though.

Comment: Sorry. I am using Java. I just updated. Sessions are handled by cookies. I'm not sure why you think that it can be a bad idea. But Google and other companies such as Yahoo also use session sharing among the subdomains.

Comment: @cloudpre I think it's a bad idea because, as I already pointed out, your URL scheme shouldn't depend on how you organize your code internally. There's absolutely no reason to expose that to your users. I'd also argue that there's scant reason to componentize most projects like this in the first place, too.